# One problem with balls in box

Tags: probability, independence

Let's have a box containing 12 balls: 3 of them are yellow and other 9 are either red or blue. I've got this to solve:

Calculate the number of red and blue balls in the box, if probability of randomly taking out exactly one yellow, one red and one blue ball is exactly $\frac{3}{11}$.

My solution goes like this:

$\frac{3}{12}\frac{R}{11}\frac{9-R}{10}=\frac{3}{11}$, where $R$ marks number of red balls. This yields $$R(9-R)=120$$
but upper equation has no solution in $\mathbb{N}$.

So, my question is simple: is my solution wrong or is the upper task ill-posed?

Comment: There are $3!$ ways that this could be chosen.

Comment: Your calculations: $\frac{3}{12}\frac{R}{11}\frac{9-R}{10}=\frac{3}{11}$, refers to the interpretation that you very specifically take out a yellow ball *and then* take out a red ball *and then* take out a blue ball specifically in that order.  My interpretation would be that you take them out simultaneously or that you take out three balls, one of each color, in *any order*.

Comment: The question should be made clearer as well, "*if probability of randomly taking out one yellow, one red and one blue is...*" should be changed to "*if when randomly selecting three balls the probability that there is one yellow, one red, and one blue is...*"  Weird things can happen if you don't make that specification because we might be drawing different numbers of balls than three some of the time: e.g. flip a coin, if heads then draw three, if tails then draw four (*thereby making it impossible to draw exactly one yellow, one red, one blue*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is exactly correct.  Your solution is almost correct.  You can choose the yellow ball in one of 3 positions, the red one in one of two positions, and the blue one is determined.  Divide the right side of your equation by 6, and you see $R=5$ or $R=4$. Then there are 3 yellow balls, 5 reds, and 4 blue ones.   Or there are 3 yellows, 4 reds, and 5 blues.

Comment: There are two correct answers that I see.  See if you can spot the other one and include that in your post as well instead of ignoring it.  That will make your answer more complete.  Also "*divide your equation by 6*" makes it sound like you are dividing both sides of the equation.  Make it clearer which side is being divided.